# Disconnected from the rest of the join graph

Tags: sql, oracle, join

My task is to query a database, selecting the number of persons that work in the most numerous department. I do the following:

```
select count(*) from Persons join Departments using (Department_id)
where Department_id = 
(select Department_id from Persons join Departments using (Department_id) 
 group by Department_id having count(*) = 
  (select max(count(*)) from Persons 
   join Departments using (Department_id) group by Department_id)
);
```

And it works fine, but I get a warning, that Persons is disconnected from the rest of the join graph. Is there something faulty with this solution? Or perhaps it could be done easier?

Comment: I don't know about that particular warning, but given your query, the `JOIN` is _probably_ not required (unless you have outdated data in Persons ?): `SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PERSONS GROUP BY Department_id ORDER BY 1 DESC) WHERE ROWNUMBER < 2`

Comment: That sounds like a message from your client, not from the database/statement.

Comment: Can you show us the complete (exact) error message? I agree with Alex that this is most probably **not** an Oracle message but something from your application.

Comment: What if two departments have the same maximum number of employees?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of the `max(count(*))` construct.  It is an Oracle extension and it changes the semantics of `group by` (which in all other cases returns one row per group).  How about just:

```
with d as (
      select count(*) as cnt
      from persons
      group by department_id
     )
select *
from d
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the join is in fact redundant. Here is my new proposed solution:

```
select count(*) from Persons
where Department_id is not null
group by Department_id
having count(*) = (select max(count(*)) from Persons
                  where Department_id is not null
                  group by Department_id);
```